# Using Regular Expression MatchCollection and backreference

Tags: .net, regex

A have a string that matches the format `[abc][def][ghi][jkl]`.  I am using the following expression to parse the string

```
expression = @"\[([\s\S]*?)\]";
```

In this case, I can see that the groups created are

```
1: abc
1: def
1: ghi
1: jkl
```

The issue is that when I loop through the `MatchCollection` and check the `match.Value` it gives me the entire item which includes the braces (i.e. `collection[0].Value = [abc]`).
How do I return only what is shown above in the created groups?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the `Groups` attribute.

`collection[0].Groups[1]`, `collection[1].Groups[1]`, etc, is the portion of the string which matched group 1.

Comment: Checking the match collection values, _matches[0], etc, shows that they actually contain the values above.  _matches[0] = "[abc]", _matches[1] = "[def]", etc.